# is terminal code in lubuntu and ubuntu the same?

Tags: lxterminal

I am a new linux user and i installed Lubuntu on my old pc. I found that learning codes of lxterminal is quite rewarding. Codes of Ubuntu are quite easily found. Are the codes for Ubuntu and Lubuntu same? and  What are the best sites to learn those?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that what you mean by "Ubuntu Code" is `bash`.

`bash` is an acronym for "Bourne-again Shell", and is the default command language for most, if not all, Unix-based systems.

As to your question; `bash` and its corresponding commands remain the same, and retain the same functionality, **throughout all Ubuntu (even Unix/Linux) distributions.**

This is not different between Lubuntu and Ubuntu- the largest difference between both of those distributions are simply the `GUI`, or Graphical User Interface (the little icons, designs, colors, etc., which you interact with, generally with the mouse). Lubuntu is a lot lighter and less resource-intensive, and uses a lighter GUI as a result.

If you want to get started in learning the `bash` shell, check out the official Ubuntu documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting

Answer (score -1):

The `terminal` code as you call it is the same for Ubuntu and for lubuntu.  Remember than the main different between the two versions is only the 'graphical user interface'.  lubuntu is less resource intensive while Ubuntu is (arguably) nicer looking.  Therefore, unless you are using some special packages the two should be the same (or can, for the most part, make them the same).

As for what is the best resource, this would be opinion based but you can certainly search in your favourite search engine for `linux terminal basics` or something of that sort and you will find a plethora of hits.

Comment: Not sure what someone must have seen as the flaw of the above answer.  It seem to answer the question just like @Patrick Negus.  Feedback would be nice to improve (that is the hole point discussed here http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16326/an-appeal-to-low-rep-users?cb=1).

Comment: I don't see a flaw in your answer, but to answer your question I have noticed something new that I haven't noticed before on this site. There is a troll who starting about a month ago has been downvoting many answers to questions after they have been put on hold. It's arrogant and stupid of this troll to assume that reviewers never make mistakes and questions don't sometimes need to be reopened.